# How to monitor Google Cloud Platform (GCP) costs on an hourly basis?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

I am running a VM instance on GCP (actually a ready Deep Learning Package: 8 CPUs, 1 Tesla V100 GPU, ..., access via a Jupyter Notebook).

Is there a way to monitor the overall usage and costs in real-time?

I am thinking about a "Live usage" link inside https://console.cloud.google.com/, which shows which products are currently used, and their price per second/hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not possible to monitor the services usage per second/hour. In case you want to analyze your projects bills, GCP offers several options that you can use for this matter, such as [Billng Cicles](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/billing-cycle), [Billing Reports](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports), Export Billing Data to a [File](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-file) or [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery) and [Visualize your spend with Data Studio](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/visualize-data); however, it is important to keep in mind that these alternatives may require certain amount of time to reflect each service usage.

Additionally, you can use the [Cloud Billing Catalog API](https://cloud.google.com/billing/v1/how-tos/catalog-api) to get the list of all the public services and SKUs metadata in a programmatic, real-time way that can be used as a complement of the cost management tools mentioned above to reconcile list pricing rates.